# How do I ask the javascript maintainers for a feature?

Tags: javascript

It's a tiny thing, but I think that figuring out this process will help me a lot in my career. I would like to suggest an alternative syntax for import statements, where instead of being `import x from "module,"` I would like to be able to type `from "module" import x.` How would I make this suggestion?

Comment: You'd need to submit [a proposal to TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposals), It's an involved process, though - the page has a link to what they expect from a proposal and other proposals. Look at a few of them to see what people propose and how.

Comment: There is about a 0% chance of that happening, if for no other reason than that it would introduce a completely new statement-opening keyword ("from").

Answer (score 0):

To propose something new, or an extension to something, you'd write up a proposal (it can be fairly high-level early on), typically in a GitHub repository, and then announce it in the [TC39 Discourse group](https://es.discourse.group/) and try to get people interested in supporting it. Ultimately you'd need to get a TC39 member interested in championing the proposal through the [proposals process](https://tc39.es/process-document/). You'll need to be registered as a non-member Ecma contributor, which you can do [here](https://ecma-international.org/memento/join.htm).

For examples of proposals, see the [TC39 proposals repository](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Comment: @Colin Sivak - FWIW, though, I don't see much chance of that minor syntax addition happening. If you really want to use it in your own projects, through, you might be able to write yourself a [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) plugin for use on your projects.

Comment: (I go through the proposals process and how TC39 works in Chapter 1 of my new book, out in June/July -- see my profile for details if you're interested.)